# Internet not working in android emulator on ubuntu 11.04

Tags: android, proxy, android-emulator, android-2.2-froyo

I have installed Android 2.2 Emulator , In it internet is not working ,

I am behind proxy, so I have entered proxy at:
"Settings" -> "Wireless & Networks" -> "Mobile Networks" -> "Access Point Names" -> "Telkila"

but still no improvements.

is there something i am missing .

This is my logcat:

```
D/SntpClient(   58): request time failed: java.net.SocketException: Address family not supported by protocol
I/java.net.Socket(  237): www.google.com/74.125.235.19(80): java.net.ConnectException: www.google.com/74.125.235.19:80 - Connection refused
I/java.net.Socket(  237): www.google.com/74.125.235.20(80): java.net.ConnectException: www.google.com/74.125.235.20:80 - Connection refused
I/java.net.Socket(  237): www.google.com/74.125.235.16(80): java.net.ConnectException: www.google.com/74.125.235.16:80 - Connection refused
I/java.net.Socket(  237): www.google.com/74.125.235.17(80): java.net.ConnectException: www.google.com/74.125.235.17:80 - Connection refused
I/java.net.Socket(  237): www.google.com/74.125.235.19(80): java.net.ConnectException: www.google.com/74.125.235.19:80 - Connection refused
I/java.net.Socket(  237): www.google.com/74.125.235.20(80): java.net.ConnectException: www.google.com/74.125.235.20:80 - Connection refused
I/java.net.Socket(  237): www.google.com/74.125.235.16(80): java.net.ConnectException: www.google.com/74.125.235.16:80 - Connection refused
I/java.net.Socket(  237): www.google.com/74.125.235.17(80): java.net.ConnectException: www.google.com/74.125.235.17:80 - Connection refused
I/java.net.Socket(  237): www.google.com/74.125.235.19(80): java.net.ConnectException: www.google.com/74.125.235.19:80 - Connection refused
I/java.net.Socket(  237): www.google.com/74.125.235.20(80): java.net.ConnectException: www.google.com/74.125.235.20:80 - Connection refused
I/java.net.Socket(  237): www.google.com/74.125.235.16(80): java.net.ConnectException: www.google.com/74.125.235.16:80 - Connection refused
I/java.net.Socket(  237): www.google.com/74.125.235.17(80): java.net.ConnectException: www.google.com/74.125.235.17:80 - Connection refused
E/Tab     (  237): onReceivedError -6 http://www.google.com/m?hl=en&gl=us&source=android-launcher-widget&q=hello The connection to the server was unsuccessful.
I/ActivityManager(   58): Starting activity: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.HOME] flg=0x10200000 cmp=com.android.launcher/com.android.launcher2.Launcher }
W/InputManagerService(   58): Ignoring hideSoftInput of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@4505fbd8
W/InputManagerService(   58): Starting input on non-focused client com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@44ea5260 (uid=10019 pid=237)
D/dalvikvm(  237): GC_EXPLICIT freed 2773 objects / 182192 bytes in 71ms
D/dalvikvm(  120): GC_EXPLICIT freed 106 objects / 4272 bytes in 91ms
D    /SntpClient(   58): request time failed: java.net.SocketException: Address family not supported by protocol
I/ActivityManager(   58): Starting activity: Intent { act=android.search.action.GLOBAL_SEARCH flg=0x14200000 pkg=com.android.quicksearchbox cmp=com.android.quicksearchbox/.SearchActivity bnds=[86,92][459,157] (has extras) }
W/InputManagerService(   58): Starting input on non-focused client com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@44f60640 (uid=10012 pid=182)
D/dalvikvm(  113): GC_EXPLICIT freed 485 objects / 22512 bytes in 70ms
I/ActivityManager(   58): Starting activity: Intent { act=android.intent.action.WEB_SEARCH flg=0x14000000 cmp=com.android.quicksearchbox/.google.GoogleSearch (has extras) }
I/ActivityManager(   58): Starting activity: Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=http://www.google.com/m?hl=en&gl=us&source=android-launcher-widget&q=hello flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.android.browser/.BrowserActivity (has extras) }
I/browser (  237): Reusing tab for com.android.quicksearchbox
W/IInputConnectionWrapper(  182): showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection
D/dalvikvm(  182): GC_EXPLICIT freed 2044 objects / 102120 bytes in 76ms
I/ActivityManager(   58): Starting activity: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.HOME] flg=0x10200000 cmp=com.android.launcher/com.android.launcher2.Launcher }
W/InputManagerService(   58): Ignoring hideSoftInput of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@450be550
W/InputManagerService(   58): Starting input on non-focused client com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@44ea5260 (uid=10019 pid=237)
D/dalvikvm(  237): GC_EXPLICIT freed 795 objects / 52256 bytes in 69ms
D/dalvikvm(  120): GC_EXPLICIT freed 33 objects / 1744 bytes in 78ms
D/SntpClient(   58): request time failed: java.net.SocketException: Address family not supported by protocol
I/ActivityManager(   58): Starting activity: Intent { act=android.search.action.GLOBAL_SEARCH flg=0x14200000 pkg=com.android.quicksearchbox cmp=com.android.quicksearchbox/.SearchActivity bnds=[86,92][459,157] (has extras) }
W/InputManagerService(   58): Starting input on non-focused client com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@44f60640 (uid=10012 pid=182)
D/dalvikvm(  108): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 563 objects / 30304 bytes in 68ms
I/ActivityManager(   58): Starting activity: Intent { act=android.intent.action.WEB_SEARCH flg=0x14000000 cmp=com.android.quicksearchbox/.google.GoogleSearch (has extras) }
I/ActivityManager(   58): Starting activity: Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=http://www.google.com/m?hl=en&gl=us&source=android-launcher-widget&q=hello flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.android.browser/.BrowserActivity (has extras) }
I/browser (  237): Reusing tab for com.android.quicksearchbox
W/IInputConnectionWrapper(  182): showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection
I/ActivityManager(   58): Starting activity: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.HOME] flg=0x10200000 cmp=com.android.launcher/com.android.launcher2.Launcher }
W/InputManagerService(   58): Ignoring hideSoftInput of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@45102f38
W/InputManagerService(   58): Starting input on non-focused client com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@44ea5260 (uid=10019 pid=237)
I/ActivityManager(   58): Starting activity: Intent { act=android.search.action.GLOBAL_SEARCH flg=0x14200000 pkg=com.android.quicksearchbox cmp=com.android.quicksearchbox/.SearchActivity bnds=[86,92][459,157] (has extras) }
W/InputManagerService(   58): Starting input on non-focused client com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@44f60640 (uid=10012 pid=182)
I/ActivityManager(   58): Starting activity: Intent { act=android.intent.action.WEB_SEARCH flg=0x14000000 cmp=com.android.quicksearchbox/.google.GoogleSearch (has extras) }
I/ActivityManager(   58): Starting activity: Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=http://www.google.com/m?hl=en&gl=us&source=android-launcher-widget&q=hello flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.android.browser/.BrowserActivity (has extras) }
I/browser (  237): Reusing tab for com.android.quicksearchbox
W/IInputConnectionWrapper(  182): showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection
D/dalvikvm(  113): GC_EXPLICIT freed 535 objects / 25976 bytes in 48ms
D/dalvikvm(  182): GC_EXPLICIT freed 4012 objects / 207464 bytes in 81ms
```

Comment: Have you set the permission in the manifest file ? <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

Comment: Take your question to google, better too!

Comment: yes, I have added the permission , but the internet is not working even in default browser.

Answer (score 0):

you do not need to set up specific networking.

The emulator makes use of NAT, therefore internet should work "out of the box" from the emulator.

I suggest you remove your entry's and see what the results are.

In fact, i tried to "enable Wifi"on my emulators, but that gives an error, wich is quite logical... An emulator cannot emulate a wireless device....

Comment: i presume you're running your emulator with Eclipse... open up your DDMS perspective, and see what Logcat has to say when you start to open the default browser... it should tell you why networking is not starting.  Also have you checked your network security?  maybe a firewall issue enforced on your computer/network?

Comment: I have added my logcat , plz check!

Comment: Hmm, it appears that there is a problem maybe with your AVD. In particular this line caught my attention:

`D    /SntpClient(   58): request time failed: java.net.SocketException: Address family not supported by protocol`

It happens sometimes.  Why, that is a mystery to me, but let's just assume taht computers are sensitive beings as well, and that computers sometimes just don't want to execute the things you would like 100%.... :D

apart from that, take a look at this question :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3190097/helloandroid-tutorial-error-request-time-failed

in short:make a new AVD